# IEEE Copyright and replacing previous ArXiv/TechRxiv versions

Tags: publications, copyright, arxiv, ieee, preprint

I know that similar questions have been posted before but i cannot find a specific and complete answer.
Suppose that i post a preprint article on ArXiv/TechRxiv. Then, i submit the paper to an IEEE Transaction journal. After revisions it is accepted. In IEEE [author's FAQ](https://www.ieee.org/content/dam/ieee-org/ieee/web/org/pubs/author_faq.pdf) i can read the following:

> Can an author post his manuscript on a preprint server such as TechRxiv or ArXiv?
> Yes. The IEEE recognizes that many authors share their unpublished manuscripts on public sites. **Once manuscripts have been accepted for publication by IEEE, an author is required to post an IEEE copyright notice on his preprint.** Upon publication, the author must ***replace*** the preprint with either 1) the full citation to the IEEE work with Digital Object Identifiers (DOI) or a link to the paper’s abstract in IEEE Xplore, or 2) the accepted version only (not the IEEEpublished version), including the IEEE copyright notice and full citation, with a link to the final, published paper in IEEE Xplore.

So, here is the question: how can i do that if ArXiv/TechRxiv does not permit to replace/edit previous version of a preprint? I am allowed just to update the preprint, hence create a [new version of it](https://arxiv.org/help/replace). However, previous versions remain accessible.

Answer (score 4):

When referring to a preprint being replaced, it is understood that a new version will be generated. Most/all preprint servers do not generally permit editing existing versions in order to maintain a clear timeline.

Even though older versions remain accessible, readers would view the latest version as the most up-to-date version to refer to for future use, so this is unlikely to be an issue.

This interpretation also agrees with the [terminology used by arXiv](https://arxiv.org/help/replace).

Answer (score 2):

I have just gone through this process with the an IEEE publication and TechRxiv.  Having 2 revisions before my paper was accepted, these two prints are archived as 2 different versions of the same record, having the same DOI with a versioned suffix.  TechRxiv always shows the newest record first.

Once your article is published on IEEE Xplore, you can download your author accepted manuscript from the Author Gateway.  This will be the same PDF as your final submission, but with the IEEE copyright and Published DOI put on the document for you.

You can then click My Submissions in TechRxiv, and edit your existing record to now include the provided AAM.

Anyone accessing TechRxiv will see your latest version by default.  This is completely acceptable with respect to IEEE policy, as can be seen from the instructions you get during the publication process, or the IEEE website.

These are the notices on the IEEE provided AAM:

> This article has been accepted for publication in IEEE Transactions on
> Electron Devices. This is the author's version which has not been
> fully edited and content may change prior to final publication.
> Citation information: DOI 10.1109/TED.2021.1234567
>
> © 2021 IEEE. Personal use is permitted, but
> republication/redistribution requires IEEE permission. See
> https://www.ieee.org/publications/rights/index.html for more
> information.

Please see these for more information:

https://www.ieee.org/content/dam/ieee-org/ieee/web/org/pubs/author_version_faq.pdf

https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/become-an-ieee-journal-author/publishing-ethics/guidelines-and-policies/post-publication-policies/

This link states that TechRxiv and ArXiv are acceptable places to store a copy of the AAM:
http://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/IEEE-Article-Sharing-and-Posting-Policies.pdf